# Show/hide text doesn't work when targeting link within div

Tags: jquery

Why does this work:
http://jsfiddle.net/4q5du/

whereas this doesn't:
http://jsfiddle.net/zcuYw/

The only thing I'm changing is that in the second one, I'm targeting a link within a div whereas in the first one, I'm targeting the link directly. Why isn't the second one working?

```
$('div.more').hide()
$('a.showmemore').click(function(){
    $(this).next('div').slideToggle()
})
```

vs

```
$('div.more').hide()
$('div.maurice a').click(function(){
    $(this).next('div').slideToggle()
})
```

Comment: The anchor is nested in the DIV, so there is no next() element within that context.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('div.more').hide()
$('div.maurice a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // As in your example, you're click on anchor so you
                        // you need to prevent default anchor behavior

    $(this)
       .parent()      // jump to .maurice
       .next('div')   // got next div 
       .slideToggle() // show effect
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div.more').hide()
$('div.maurice a').click(function(e, ui) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().next('div').slideToggle()
})
```

You were shy one `.parent()`.

Comment: You actually need to combine paradox's un-edited answer and mine.. you'll need the `e.preventDefault();` to keep from jumping to the link.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work.

you have this code

```
$('div.more').hide()
   $('div.maurice a').click(function(){
   $(this).next('div').slideToggle()
});
```

With this HTML

```
<div class="maurice"><a href="#">Hello</a></div>
<div class="more">
    Hey Ohhhh
</div>
```

And when you click on the `a` you want to slide toggle the next `div` element when there is no such thing, the `next()` function returns direct siblings, so in your case you need to go up one level with `parent()` and then use just `next()`

Result being

```
$('div.more').hide()
$('div.maurice a').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().next('div').slideToggle()
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zcuYw/1/**

Comment: @DevlshOne I have just up-voted yours I wouldn't wan't to steal your votes. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Click on `$('div.maurice a')` does not work cause `next()`

```
$(this).next('div').slideToggle();
```

in

```
<div class="maurice"> <a href="#">THIS</a>  NO ELEMENT HERE </div>
<div class="more">
    IT'S HERE!
</div>
```

does not exists

You should go one up (`.parent()` or `.closest('div')`) and than target the `.next()`